# Can you be an eligible post-mortem organ donor candidate when you are traveling abroad?

Tags: international-travel, regulations

[Some countries have opt-in arrangements, others have opt-out arrangements](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2571/which-organ-donor-law-applies-when-you-die-as-an-expat) when it comes to post-mortem organ donorship.

What happens if you die while traveling abroad? Is your body lost in transit, or are there ways to remain a valid donor to save someones life?

Answer (score 2):

The German Federal Centre for Health Education offers [donor cards in many languages](http://www.organspende-info.de/organspendeausweis/beiblaetter) specifically for this purpose. They do warn that the local rules apply by default (*Grundsätzlich gilt immer die Regelung des jeweiligen Landes*) but they claim the card would generally be honored.

Beyond the implementation details (opt-in, opt-out, central register or not, etc.) the rules generally give a strong weight to the wishes of the deceased. It does therefore make sense that carrying a document expressing those wishes unambiguously in the local language would make it more likely that your organs would be used following your instructions.

Comment: Does that mean that whenever I travel across the world, it would be sensible for me to carry said document? What if I have an insurance which supports repatriation of remains? Then what happens?